# PayPal authorization link redirects user nowhere and keeps a loop in the same PayPal site

Tags: redirect, paypal, postman, paypal-sandbox, hateoas

I have a situation, not solved. I still have tried workaround with no success, same loop returning to same form in the PayPal website. I see the button is CONTINUE instead of PAY NOW. Is it maybe a clue?

Here an example of the API request in Postman, and the response:

```
https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders
```

Payload

```
    {
  "intent": "AUTHORIZE",
  "purchase_units": [
        {
          "amount": {
            "currency_code": "USD",
            "value": "100",
            "breakdown": {
                   "item_total":{
                                  "currency_code": "USD",
                                  "value": "100"
                   },
                   "shipping":{
                                  "currency_code": "USD",
                                  "value": "0"
                   },
                   "tax_total":{
                                  "currency_code": "USD",
                                "value": "0"
                   },
                   "shipping_discount":{
                                  "currency_code": "USD",
                                  "value": "0"
                   }
            }
          },
         
          "items": [
                   {
                   "name": "Item #1234",
                   "unit_amount":{
                                  "currency_code": "USD",
                                  "value": "100"
                   },
                   "tax": {
                                  "currency_code": "USD",
                                  "value": "0"
                   },
                   "quantity": "1",
                   "description": "Company Name",
                   "sku": "tel:+12065555555",
                   "custom": "My Custom Data"
          }]
        }
      ]
}
```

RESPONSE (201 - CREATED)

```
{
    "id": "8W523711V28300745",
    "status": "CREATED",
    "links": [
        {
            "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/8W523711V28300745",
            "rel": "self",
            "method": "GET"
        },
        {
            "href": "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/checkoutnow?token=8W523711V28300745",
            "rel": "approve",
            "method": "GET"
        },
        {
            "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/8W523711V28300745",
            "rel": "update",
            "method": "PATCH"
        },
        {
            "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/8W523711V28300745/authorize",
            "rel": "authorize",
            "method": "POST"
        }
    ]
}
```

So, the link to follow for an user in a browser is:

```
 https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/checkoutnow?token=8W523711V28300745
```

Inside this link, after authorize the order, the PayPal website is ot redirecting anyplace, is a loop back to same form. However I get the notification about the approval. I think it is confusing for the user experience to be in that loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you are redirecting the user over to the `approval_url`, then your original API request should have included a `return_url`, so PayPal knows where to return the customer.  A return from the approval is required, so that you can capture the order, otherwise there will be no payment.

The best integration uses no redirects whatsoever. In place of sending the browser to the approval URL, all you need is to create the order and get back its `id` value. Then use that to show a button that gives an in-context checkout experience, keeping your site loaded in the background (no redirect away). Once the buyer gives their approval, you'll then do the API call to capture the order.  Here is the demo code: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

It's actually very simple/straightforward, most of the stuff at the end is some pointers about post-capture error handling